# Java connection timeout exception (server is in virtual machine)

Tags: java, exception, get, centos, vmware

I'm havin this situation. I have server running in CentOS (CentOS is in my virtual machine VMware). In host (win7) I have java program that needs to make GET method to server on CentOS. I've manage connection between host and virtual machine and thing works from browser and java program in CentOS and from browser in host (win7) but not from java program in host which is what I need. 
If I turn off virtual machine I still get timeout exception.
I've turn off firewall on win7 but i can't turn it off in CentOS because I don't have admin permission.

This is my java code for GET method (192.168.11.128 is IP of virtual machine) :

```
private static void getMethod(){
    // Create a method instance.
    GetMethod method = new GetMethod("http://192.168.11.128");

    // Provide custom retry handler is necessary
    method.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER,
            new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler(3, false));

    try {
      // Execute the method.
      int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);

      if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        System.err.println("Method failed: " + method.getStatusLine());
      }

      // Read the response body.
      byte[] responseBody = method.getResponseBody();

      // Deal with the response.
      // Use caution: ensure correct character encoding and is not binary data
      System.out.println(new String(responseBody));

    } catch (HttpException e) {
      System.err.println("Fatal protocol violation: " + e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Fatal transport error: " + e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      // Release the connection.
      method.releaseConnection();
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!